# Changing systemd user with drop-in replacement for transmission-daemon not working

Tags: debian, systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, transmission

So after some research I found the existence of drop-ins for systemd service units.

I'm trying to get the `transmission-daemon` package running as the `pi` user since it's the only way to get correct permission in the folder it downloads to. By default it runs as `debian-transmission`. I want to steer away from init.d and choose a systemd approach.

Described in the systemd file (`/lib/system/systemd/transmission-daemon.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=debian-transmission
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With my drop-in replacement in `/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/local.conf`:

```
[Service]
User=
User=pi
Group=pi
```

I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart transmission-daemon`. The drop-in is listed in `sudo systemctl status transmission-daemon` and shows as active nevertheless the daemon isn't running correctly and RPC connection doesn't work in a browser.

Thanks in advance if you help, because I'm fumbled.

Comment: Please check which user account the transmission-daemon process is actually running as (after you start it):

    ps auxww | grep transmission-daemon

also, is there are any errors or warnings in the logs ?

journalctl -u transmission-daemon --since today

Comment: Also do you really need this empty "User=" entry in your local.conf ?
(should not break it, but still)

Comment: @zeppelin Just verified what was in original post, transmission-daemon runs as special user `debian-transmission` as described in the env USER `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`. No journal files found (due to the package using init.d?) The empty User= was removed but makes no difference.

Comment: Hmm, well, so it is still being started by the SystemV init script ? And systemd will try to launch a second instance of it (which explains why it does not work well).

Please disable the init script with `update-rc.d transmission-daemon disable`, stop it `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop`, verify that the process is not running with `ps`, and then start a systemd unit: `systemctl start transmission-daemon`, and see if it works (or at least produces some usable logs now).

Comment: You may also try to add --log-info to your ExecStart command, to make it produce a bit more detailed log.

Comment: Tried that but no result. Stoping & disabling the init.d script produces: `insserv: warning: current stop runlevels (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script transmission-daemon overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).` I found the repo online and will see to file a bug there.

Comment: Ok, but what if you just stop it `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop` and run the systemd unit `systemctl start transmission-daemon` ?
(the LSB error you see can be fixedl, but it is a bit out of scope for now)

Comment: Seems like this problem is not with systemd but solely with transmission-daemon having two seperate and differently owned config folders. Will answer my own question. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer myself:

Systemd is not the problem since it runs the service correctly but when transmission-daemon runs as the pi user it reads the config from `$HOME/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json` owned by `pi:pi`, instead of `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` owned by `debian-transmission:debian-transmission`.

As a solution you can switch to using the config file in `$HOME/transmission-daemon` or pass `-g /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` in an ExecStart directive in the drop-in.